# Exponential integral times exponential

Tags: real-analysis, integration, exponential-function

Let us define the exponential integral $E_{1}(x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t} \mathrm{d}t$, with $x$ positive real.

Is there any way to simplify the following product?

$$e^{x} E_{1}(x)$$

I've tried to rewrite the exponential integral using the incomplete gamma function, i.e., $E_{1}(x) = \Gamma(0,x)$ but it does not simplify anything. I've also considered the "continued fraction expansion" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Approximations: if I multiply the exponential integral by the exponential, we get rid of the exponential in the numerator of the "continued fraction expansion", but the expression remains intractable.

Comment: What is the context of this problem?

Comment: @D.R. Shannon capacity of MIMO communication channels.

Comment: Well, according to the Wiki page you have
$e^x E_1(x) = U(1,1,x)$ with Tricomi's confluent hypergeometric function,
see also http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.11,  and there is an 
[asyptotic expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Asymptotic_%28divergent%29_series)

Comment: @gammatester Thanks. It really looks like there is no tractable expression, i.e., one that does not involved "masked integrals"...

Comment: Do you want an analytic simplification? If you want to compute actual values, the asymptotic expression looks good with error bounds given in more detail at http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12, and the Kummer/Tricomi U function can be computed without integrals.

Comment: @TheDon : Why do you say that $e^x E_1(x)$ is a "no tractable expression" ? $E_1(x)$ is a nice special function often easier to handle than many other functions. Don't you like what you call  "masked integrals" ?. If it is the case, you deprive yourself from a lot of well known standard functions. Among them, you deprive yourself from the function $ln(x)=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$ don't you ? Have a kook through : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales

Comment: @gammatester Thanks for pointing this out. Unfortunately the analytic expansion is not enough for my case (I need to take derivatives and solve for $x$). To compute actual values I would rather use the exact expression (using Matlab or Mathematica) without resorting to approximations.

Comment: @JJacquelin I absolutely love "masked integrals" :). However, the presence of $e^{x} E_{1}(x)$ prevents me to find a closed-form solution to a specific problem that I'm dealing with. I was hoping I could get rid of this term by rewriting it in some nicer, "unmasked" form.

Comment: @TheDon : Nobody can help you if you ask a question without explaining what is your "specific problem".

Comment: @JJacquelin: Is there a freely available copy of your linked Safari document?

Comment: @gammatester: As far as I know, it is possible to download the document. Let me know it there is some trouble in downloading.

Comment: @JJacquelin: The site shows `\NINXG GD ]FB LARD]XW AI ]FB \ZBLGNC IRDL]GAD\ 0 pp.>6-<9 Zravgsgadnc trndscntgad (Altahbr 88, 8:>8)`. May be I should `Sign in` or `Join`, but the corresponding pages show some text and a white square, and IMO this is not freely available.

Comment: @gammatester:  I could send you a copy, but I don't know how do that without making public the personal e-mails, which is not recommended. Sorry.

Comment: Define "simplify". The only way this would simplify is if $E_1(x)$ could simplify, and as far as I'm concerned, it doesn't, being a transcendental special function.

Answer (score 0):

The only operation in the way to simplify this is integrating by parts the $E_1$:

$$E_1\left( x\right) = \int_x^\infty d\left(e^{-t}lnt\right) + \int_x^\infty e^{-t}lnt\ dt = -e^{-x}lnx + \int_x^\infty e^{-t}lnt\ dt$$

Then:

$$e^xE_1\left( x \right) = -lnx + e^x\int_x^\infty e^{-t}lnt\ dt$$

Answer (score 0):

If there was a known simplification, we would not be using the function $E_1$, but instead that simplified function times $e^{-x}$.